# Substitute for eqnarray?

Tags: align, eqnarray

Firstly, sorry for my english level, I'm French.
Secondly, I've read `eqnarray` environment becomes obsolete, and we have to replace this by `align`. Ok, but it's not satisfying for me. I explain :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} % Tableaux, maths
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
  Test~eqnarray*   & = & \text{Good alignment} \\
  & Because & \text{the text is aligned near to the equal sign}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

gives this :
[image]

With the environment `align`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} % Tableaux, maths
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  Test~align*   & = & \text{Bad alignment} \\
  & Because & \text{the text is right-aligned, far to the equal sign}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

gives :

[image]

How can I obtain absolutly the same results as `eqnarray` with `align` ?

Note : I don't care the spacing problem with `eqnarray`

Comment: Is `\begin{align*}
  Test~align*   & = \text{Bad alignment} \\
  & = \text{Because the text is aligned near to the equal sign}
\end{align*}` OK for you or do you want the excessive space around the equal sign?

Comment: No the spacing is ok here, but as said below, I want to aligne `Because` with `=`

Comment: In that case it might make sense to change the `eqnarray*` example to show that as well. At first glance your question read as if you wanted to align two `=`s.

Comment: I want to align both `=` (centered) and the text after (left-aligned)

Comment: But doesn't `\begin{align*} Test~align* & = \text{Bad alignment} \\ & = \text{Because the text is aligned near to the equal sign} \end{align*}` do more or less that if both lines contain a `=`? If not, then the alignment would be different, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I've change my MWE.

Comment: @Alex, this is not possible with `align` nor with `alignat`, but with array you can achieve this. see addendum to answer.

Comment: Ok, but it's not very satisfying to use `array` for equations... And, is it possible with array to numerate equations automatically if I want ?

Comment: see http://tug.org/~hvoss

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to understand that in `align` and similar amsmath environments, if you want *n* alignment groups,  each group except the first requires  2 ampersands: the first `&` introduces a new alignment group, and the second `&` specifies the alignment point inside this group. The first group doesn't require the first ampersand, of course, so *n* alignment groups in all require 2 *n* – 1 `&`s.

You have used the `eqnarray` syntax, with two `&`, so amsmath understands there are two groups. As there's no `&` for the alignment point in the second group, it is aligned on the last characters of each line.

*Added*:

An easy solution to your problem is obtained with the `eqparbox` package. Incidentally, I simplified your code for geometry (since all your margins are equal you can simply set `margin =`). Also, the `frenchb` option is ibsolete, and should be replaced with `french`, preferable loaded with the `\documentclass`, so that all language-dependent packages be informed. Lastn needless to load `amsfonts`, since `amssymb` does it for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % Tableaux, maths
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqrel}[2][B]{\mathrel{\eqmakebox[#1]{#2}}} %% eqparbox uses a system of tags, which is the optional argument here – defaults to B.

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \emph{Test~align*} &\eqrel{$=$} \text{Bad alignment} \\
  &\eqrel{\em Because} \text{the text is left-aligned, near the equal sign}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you it's interesting, even if I don't success to have that I want for now

Comment: You want `because`  to be aligned with the  `=`  sign?

Comment: Yes, and the text in the first line left-aligned with the text in the second line (see my changed MWE)

Comment: It is a solution yes, not very practical but I can enumerate my equations. Thank you for your help

Comment: I've defined an, `\eqrel`  command  to simplify typing.

Comment: Yep, I know this method. I have now to think about it when I want to do this. Thanks

Comment: Do you think I should add it? I guessed everyone interested would a loook at the documentation of `eqparbox` and see it works with a system of tags.

Comment: I've added a comment next to the code defining `\eqrel`.

Answer (score 6):

in `align` you have one ampersand to much:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} % Tableaux, maths
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  Test~align*   & = \text{Bad alignment} \\
  Because       & = \text{the text is right-aligned, far to the equal sign}
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
  Test~align*   & = \text{Bad alignment} \\
                & \text{Because the text is right-aligned, far to the equal sign}
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
  Test~align*   & = \parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{
                    Bad alignment \\
                    Because the text is right-aligned, far to the equal sign}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**adedndum:**
apparently you looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{array}{rcl}
  Test~array    & =         & \text{Fine alignment}\\
                & Because   & \text{the text is left-aligned \dots}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**addendum (2):**
with help of very old (and almost forgotten) package `mathenv` from `mfwtools`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathenv}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry} % Marges

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}[rc@{\;}l]
  Test~eqnarray &   =     & \text{Good alignment} \\
                & Because & \text{the text is aligned near to the equal sign}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I want `Because` to be aligned with `=`. Is this possible ?

Comment: @Alex, of course. you just need to place ampersand before `Because` if you like to have it below right text

Comment: Sorry, I've changed my MWE to reveal better that I want

Comment: @Alex, this is not possible to achieve with `align`, but with `array` is simple. see addendum to answer.

Comment: Yes it's perfect. But I can't enumerate my equations if necessary... Can I ?

Comment: @Alex, as complete system. individual equation no.

Comment: Ok, so I don't have the flexibility I had with `eqnarray`. Never mind. Thank you !

Comment: see one more solution, with `eqnaray`, but somehow improved.

Comment: I use this, but precisely I've read that the `eqnarray` environment is obsolete. What is the impact of `mathenv` package here, relative to my MWE (if you remove the star) ?

Comment: @Alex, it enables to define columns, and make better spacing.

Comment: Ok yes I've seen. Thanks for the proposition